# Calculate if today's date is a recurring date for a given date

Tags: python, django, date

Given a 'start' date, and a frequency (monthly, quarterly, bi-annually, annually), how can I calculate if today is a date to perform the desired action?

For example, the start date is 2010-01-01, and the frequency is monthly. A cron job will run a Django management command every day, so on 2010-02-01, the desired action should be performed (whatever that may be, not important for this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually simpler than I originally thought. Because all of these intervals occur on the month, its quite simple to calculate it. It makes use of the `relativedelta` object in `dateutil`.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

starts_at = date(2010, 1, 1)
today = date(2010, 2, 1)  # as an example
diff = relativedelta(today, starts_at)

if diff.days == 0:  # there must be no days difference between two dates
    if diff.months % 12 == 0:  # this is a year interval
        do_something('annual')
    elif diff.months % 6 == 0:  # this is a six month interval
        do_something('bi_annual')
    elif diff.months % 3 == 0:  # this is a three month interval
        do_something('quarter')
    else:  # this is a month interval
        do_something('month')
```

Comment: I presume  each  `do_something()` is  different?

Comment: Also won't  `diff.months % 1` always be 0?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've updated the answer, and thanks for pointing out that error.

Comment: You may want to start at 12, `12 % 3 == 0` or even when a year has passed you will never reach the elif for you six or 12 month interval, the last elif can also just be else as it will always be True

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Does that look better?

Answer (score 2):

To find whether today is a recurring date, you could use `today in recurring_rule`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY  # $ pip install python-dateutil

starts_at = datetime(2010, 1, 1)
today = datetime(2010, 2, 1) 
interval = {'monthly': 1, 'quarterly': 3,
            'bi-annually': 6, 'annually': 12}[frequency]
if today in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=starts_at, interval=interval):
    print('today is a recurring date')
```

[`dateutil.rrule`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57) allows you to create recurring rules according to [RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10).

It is probably an overkill if you need to support only simple rules with monthly, quarterly, bi-annually, annually frequencies but it can be useful in more complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome [`Delorean` library](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) that has the related [`stops()` function](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#making-a-few-stops). The idea is to find if today's date is one of the "stops" of a range. Sample implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime

import delorean
from delorean import stops


def is_it_time(start_date, frequency):
    today = datetime.now()
    today_date = today.date()

    try:
        next(stop for stop in stops(frequency, start=start_date, stop=today)
             if stop.date == today_date)
        return "It's time."
    except StopIteration:
        return "It's not the time."

print is_it_time(datetime(2010, 1, 21), delorean.MONTHLY)  
print is_it_time(datetime(2010, 1, 22), delorean.MONTHLY)
```

Prints:

```
It's time.
It's not the time.
```

Note that `frequency` here has to be one of the `Delorean` frequency constants, but, if you need custom frequency values - just map them into the `Delorean` constants appropriately.